# New Exchange Bid Ask and Price values

Tags: stock-markets, markets

Imagine you are starting up new exchange / exchange simulator
The orderbook is empty.

What would be the current price, bid & ask ?

How is that handled? Obviously it can't be ZERO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hypothetical question unrelated to personal finance.

Comment: It could be reworded to ask how exchanges are started up and how IPOs and bond auctions work as that would be pretty much on topic as far as I understand and would contain the same information in response just reworded a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do what all exchanges currently do for new issues - hold an auction. Start at a price that values the company as worth its book value (or 0) and get investors to bid up or down the price until all of the quantity is sold. The other way to do it is ask how much people want and how much they would pay for it and then start at the highest price filling quantities until all of the quantity is done then make the price the lowest of the prices at which quantity was filled. This is a modified Dutch auction which is how US treasuries are sold. Either way the bid = the ask at the price you have determined and then orders go on to set the prices thereafter.

Comment: Very helpfull answer.